# How to minimize the execution timing while running nested for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

How I can reduce the code execution time while running the nested loops in javascript. I am explaining my sample code below which contains some nested for loop.

```
let arr1 = [1, -3, 2, 3, 6, -1];
let arr2 = [4, 8, 9, -4, 1, -1, -8, -9];
let arr3 = [6, 3, -1, -3, 4, -2, 2, 4, 6, -12, -7];

function countZeroSumSubArray(arr) {
  let sum = 0;
  let counter = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum = 0;
    for (let j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
      sum += arr[j];
      if (!sum) {
        ++counter;
      }
    }

  }
  return counter
}

console.log('amount:', countZeroSumSubArray(arr1))
console.log('amount:', countZeroSumSubArray(arr2))
console.log('amount:', countZeroSumSubArray(arr3))
```

Here I may face execution time issue if my given array length is too long. I need to reduce those execution time or implement some other way where I can reduce the execution time and get the proper output also.

Comment: why are you iterating over same array twice?

Comment: arr.filter(v => v === 0).length;  counts the number of 0 in the array

Comment: Here My requirement is to get number of subarrays whose sum is zero of given array.

Comment: arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) === 0

Comment: but in your code - there are no subarrays, and your loop iterates the same arr

Comment: Can you post your answer so that I will run it and match with the proper output.

Comment: maybe - if you post data with subarrays in

Comment: Here `I have to find the number of subarrays in a given array whose sum is zero`

Comment: @developer: This code is also working fine but I need to reduce the execution time as we know for loops usually takes much time.

Comment: ref: https://github.com/dg92/Performance-Analysis-JS